# Vercel not triggering new commits on Github

Tags: github, deployment, vercel

**Vercel is not triggering new commits on Github.**

Hi everyone! It was fine, but Vercel deployed the commits but didn't make any changes. I thought I didn't push the changes, but I did. I don't know why it suddenly did that, but it's pretty weird.

Any solutions would be appreciated!

I tried to re-deploy, but it made no difference. I was expecting Vercel to deploy my project correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/git), Vercel allows for automatic deployments on every branch push and merges onto the Production Branch of your GitHub, GitLab, and Bitbucket projects.

The [production branch](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/git#production-branch) is selected in the following order:

> - The main branch.
> - If not present, the master branch (more details).
> - [Only for Bitbucket] If not present, the "Production Branch" setting of your Git repository is used.
> - If not present, the Git repository's default branch.

So it is possible you have pushed your commits to a different branch.
Check `git status` and `git branch -avv` to check:

- on which local branch you are
- what upstream branch is associated with your local branch

Comment: Hi VonC! Thanks for your answer, it managed to randomly work by itself. But thank you, this might be an answer to other people!

Comment: @Zeptar1069 Great, glad you made it work.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. @Zeptar1069 can you explain what worked for you?

Comment: @tblancog I did git commit and push again, it worked for me

Answer (score 1):

I'm late, but maybe you should try build project, then push it to git and then see what happend.

Vercel is connected to repository correctly, shows changes, everthing is fine.

But, **Root Directory** is build folder, so if you don't build again he does not recognize any changes.

Go to project settings, scroll down you'll see **Root Directory**.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Turns out I was committing on the 'beta' branch, not the main branch by accident.

Comment: No problem, thanks for update :)

Comment: I have the same problem, I only have one branch, the main branch. I can see changed committed files in github repo, but Vercel did not auto deploy a new version.

Comment: Do you see changed commit files in build folder?